# PS5/PC Audiomixer

Tags: pc, audio, audio-adapters

I have a PS5, a PC, Speakers and a Headset. I'm looking for a device to connect all these together. I want to hear the audio of PS5 and PC at the same time with my Headset or Speakers. A button to switch my mic between PS5 and PC. And a button to switch the audio output between Headset and Speakers.